# Is Tor private when i am connecting to google from the same machine?

Tags: google

For example: On my windows computer, i am visiting a website on the Tor browser. At the same time, i am watching a youtube video on google Chrome on the same windows computer.

Can google know which site i am visiting on Tor?

Comment: See: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38316/tor-and-regular-browser-side-by-side-does-that-make-sense, https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7584/using-tor-browser-and-chrome-firefox-simultaneously, https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/921/does-a-tor-enabled-browser-affect-other-browsers, and https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4661/do-i-have-to-uninstall-my-other-browsers-before-using-tor-browser-bundle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Tor browser and Chrome/Firefox simultaneously](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7584/using-tor-browser-and-chrome-firefox-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

You can use both browsers simultaneously without compromising the security or anonymity of your usage of Tor Browser. The two browsers do not affect each other, and store their configuration information in independent locations. Do keep in mind, however, that you might potentially accidentally use the non-private browser to access something that you intended to access using Tor Browser.

Additionally, as other answers have [pointed out](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/38450), there may be certain risks to your privacy in the form of cookie extraction and timing-based attacks.